# LaTeX for word style divide?

Tags: math-operators, inline

In microsoft word equation, it's possible to write `a / b` in a format that `a` is slightly upper than normal text, the `/` can be entered using `\ldivide`.

Is it possible to do so in LaTeX?

Comment: Why was this tagged `biblatex`? Do you mean text fractions a/b?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thanks for updating the tagging to the correct ones. yes, something like "a/b", it'll be easier for inline formula

Comment: I did not retag it ;-) Others noted it already too...

Comment: Hi! You mean [`nicefrac`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nicefrac)? If yes, then please do not do that.

Comment: Agreed with @tohecz, there is also [`xfrac`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xfrac), but I do not recommend it...

Comment: @tohecz and that's because...?

Comment: You have three options: (1) You keep the size of the letters unchanged and then you have to align them vertically, as in `a/b`. (2) You make them smaller and you use the standard fraction, as in `\frac{a}{b}`. (3) You make them unaligned with a diagonal fraction line, as in `\nicefrac{a}{b}`, but then you need to make the letters smaller anyways and you gain nothing compared to `\frac{a}{b}`. Such fractions are useless and ugly. Moreover, in some cases they can be quite confusing (consider for instance `3\nicefrac{a}{b}` vs. `3^a/b`).